# SwiftUI view does not reload after @State variable changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple setup like this in `FeedView` :

```
    public struct FeedView: View {
    var loadFeed: () -> Void
    @State private var feed: [SwiftUIFeedItem]
    
    public init(feed: [SwiftUIFeedItem] = [], loadFeed: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.loadFeed = loadFeed
        self.feed = feed
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        List(feed) { item in
            FeedRow(item: item)
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
        .refreshable {
            loadFeed()
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadFeed()
        }
    }
    
    public func display(_ feed: [SwiftUIFeedItem]) {
        self.feed = feed
    }
}
```

And in composition root I add loading feed logic and update the view

```
public final class FeedSwiftUIComposer {
    private init() {}
    
    public static func feedComposedWith(feedLoader: FeedLoader) -> FeedView {
        
        let adapter = FeedSwiftUIViewPresentationAdapter(feedLoader: feedLoader)
        let feedView = FeedView(loadFeed: adapter.didRequestLoadFeed)
        
        adapter.feedView = feedView
        
        return feedView
    }
    
}

final class FeedSwiftUIViewPresentationAdapter {
    var feedView: FeedView?
    private let feedLoader: FeedLoader
    
    init(feedLoader: FeedLoader) {
        self.feedLoader = feedLoader
    }
    
    func didRequestLoadFeed() {
        feedLoader.load { [weak self] result in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            if let feed = try? result.get() {
                self?.feedView?.display(feed.map {
                    SwiftUIFeedItem(id: $0.id, description: $0.description, location: $0.location, url: $0.url)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After debugging I've noticed that the `display(_)` method was get called but the `feed` variable was not being updated thus the view was not updated.
I'm new to SwiftUI and not sure what's wrong with my code.
Please help. Thanks

Comment: You cannot hold a reference to a View (which is a value type). Instead, share your state in an ObservableObject and pass that to your View.

Comment: Understand now. Solved with an observable object